# Host Controls update using Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-meet

How can I update/set the host controls' Quick Add settings to **off** while creating event using google calendar api. I want to achieve that when the host is not present in the meeting, no one else can join.

Image showing host controls:

[image: hostControls]

My current api call in javascript is provided below which successfully creates the event.

```
gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
                "calendarId": "primary",
                "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
                "resource": {
                    "end": {
                        "date": eDate
                    },
                    "start": {
                        "date": sDate
                    },
                    "conferenceData": {
                        "createRequest": {
                            "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                                "type": "hangoutsMeet"
                            },
                            "requestId": "@(new Guid().ToString())"
                        }
                    },
                    "summary": "@(Model.Title+" Class Meeting")"
                }
            })
```

I have read the documentation as well but cannot find this setting. https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert

Comment: If the option you are looking for is not contained in the [event resouce](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource) it means that the respective endpoint has not been implemented into the API (yet). You can file a respective [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

Comment: I'd love to be able to manipulate the new features of Google Meet via the API as well.  Expecially Host Controls / Adding Co-hosts.  If you have submitted a feature request please share the link!

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/208860809

Comment: I am also looking for managing co-hosts. If anybody submitted a request please post it here